# Material Autocomplete - startWith operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to implement the Material Autocomplete, and while I have it working I'm trying to figure out exactly what the startWith operator is doing in the sample code:

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-display-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-display-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-display-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteDisplayExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[] = [
    {name: 'Mary'},
    {name: 'Shelley'},
    {name: 'Igor'}
  ];
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | User>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

So the other examples I've looked at basically say that startWith is used to provide an initial value, but I don't see how:

```
 startWith<string | User>(''),
```

is doing that.  Help, ELI5!

Comment: Not really, why would you want it to emit an empty value first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the generic type `<string | User>` and focus on the value of the passed in parameter. The value that is actually passed to `startWith` in your code is an empty string `''`.

> why would you want it to emit an empty value first

In this case so that the returned observable (that is then consumed as the options in the material auto complete) has some starting values, presumably sorted alphabetically so the user is not forced to start typing or open the drop down to make the first server side call to get some selectable values.

---

#### [Documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html)

> #### StartWith
>
> emit a specified sequence of items before beginning to emit the items from the source Observable
>
> If you want an Observable to emit a specific sequence of items before it begins emitting the items normally expected from it, apply the StartWith operator to it.

### Example / Edit

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvyh9d-ksgwot). Open the console in the output window and notice the immediate output `'Filtering on value '`. Now edit the component typescript file and comment out the line with `startWith` and re-run the app. Notice how the initial `console.log` is not emitted and if you want the auto complete to show any options you have to start typing.

Comment: Igor, thanks for your response, but still confused.  How does passing in an empty produce starting values?  Does passing in the empty string actually do anything?  Sorry if these questions seem basic, trying to get my head around reactive programming and it's confusing.

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild - so the auto complete binds to the text box change event. Every time the user types that textbox input a server side call is made with that input and the observable then emits a new result from the server based on that input. Without `startWith` nothing has triggered or been emitted until the user starts typing in that input. (continued)...

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild - now lets add a functional requirement that the auto complete should be populated with some initial values. That is solved with `startWith`, a server call is made passing in empty string (but could really be anything if you want to change that) and gets a result based on that which is probably just the top X results sorted by something so that the user does not start with nothing.

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild - does that make more sense?

Comment: I think so.  So there wouldn't be any values in the autocomplete.  In the case of the example code, since we're passing in a space, basically all of the values in the User options array are in there already?

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild - see the edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I think I get it now, that last edit helped make it click.  Thanks for sticking with me on this @Igor!